# "depmod" is not allowed to be used

Tags: android-x86

I am trying to build android-x86
https://www.android-x86.org/source.html
Branch q-x86
Using ubuntu 20.
I followed the instructions and installed all the dependencies mentioned at the page. But I am facing the following error. I don`t know how to deal with it. Google search did not help me at all.

```
DEPMOD  4.19.175-android-x86-gad005d7cff5c
"depmod" is not allowed to be used. See https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/master/Changes.md#PATH_Tools for more information.
make[1]: *** [/home/nadir/androidx86/kernel/Makefile:1404: _modinst_post] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/nadir/androidx86/out/target/product/x86/obj/kernel'
make: *** [Makefile:146: sub-make] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/home/nadir/androidx86/kernel'
FAILED: [W][2021-05-16T08:15:17-0400][535663] void cmdline::logParams(nsjconf_t *)():250 Process will be UID/EUID=0 in the global user namespace, and will have user root-level access to files
[W][2021-05-16T08:15:17-0400][535663] void cmdline::logParams(nsjconf_t *)():260 Process will be GID/EGID=0 in the global user namespace, and will have group root-level access to files
08:41:17 ninja failed with: exit status 1
```

How to deal with this because the URL mentioned in the error does not help in this case. On that page there is not even a single time depmode or anything related to it mentioned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out what was happening after I had the same issue. As I can see the answer can technically be found in the link the error gives you, but the error and fix don’t make a whole lot of correlation. I attempted to fix this problem by giving my non-root user permission to execute `depmod` with `sudo` without a password. After some trial and error I discovered the lines that called depmod were on lines 20 and 48 of the `kernel/scripts/depmod.sh`, I amended the two lines by adding sudo in the front and restarted my build. However, I got a different error, “sudo is not allowed to be used”. This really got my thinking.

So I checked that link they gave for the AOSP source code. In the “PATH Tools” section it states:

> The build has started restricting the ***external host tools*** usable inside the build. …

This led me to two ways of working out the issue. First one which is likely the easiest is to add `TEMPORARY_DISABLE_PATH_RESTRICTIONS=true` after your command to build the kernel. As you may guess this would disable the restriction that is disallowing the depmod command. The alternative option is to open the file `build/soong/ui/build/paths/config.go` and add the line `"depmod": Allowed,` like so:

```
“date”:     Allowed,
“dd”:       Allowed,
“depmod”:   Allowed,
“diff”:     Allowed,
“egrep”:    Allowed,
```

Both methods allowed me to build the kernel as expected. However, it is only a workaround for something that I can’t identify as a Ubuntu issue or an oversight by the Android x86 developers. Likely a patch would need to be proposed, but since I don’t know more than about the Android kernel ecosystem, I’m unable to know if just adding the command to the allowed configuration will fix it.

Comment: Worked like a shine. Thanks.